# Can voluptuous code pass pylint?

Tags: python, pylint, voluptuous

I run `pylint -E` as part of the tests on my Python project to ensure that  errors don't creep into untested code. Generally this works quite well. But recently I've been running into problems with [voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous) and pylint.

The problem is that pylint thinks that the values returned by voluptuous Schemas are lists, which is simply not the case. Here's a toy program:

```python
import voluptuous

MyType = voluptuous.Schema({
    'q': str
})


def foo(bar):
    bar = MyType(bar)
    q = bar.get('q')
    print q


foo({'q': '1324'})
```

It runs just fine:

```
$ python toy.py
1234
```

pylint, however, flags the `.get()` call:

```
$ pylint -E toy.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module toy
E: 11, 8: Instance of 'list' has no 'get' member (no-member)
```

How can I get this program to pass `pylint -E`?

Comment: You could explicitly flag it - `# pylint: disable=no-member`.

Comment: I'd hoped to avoid having to flag that each and every time I used voluptuous.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to ignore the `voluptuous` module entirely, e.g.

```
$ pylint -E --ignored-modules=voluptuous toy.py
(passes)
```

If would be nice if `pylint` understood `voluptuous` better, though.